# html image element not showing image

Tags: html, angularjs, image

I am using a Ionic 2 popover, to display an image. However, the image is not displaying in the `modal`.

I have the following code. How do I get it to display the image?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  template: `
    <ion-content padding id="image-popover">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col>
            <center>
                <img class="item-stable" src="{{image}} height="75" width="75""/>
                <p>{{text}}</p>
            </center>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  `
})
export class ImagePopOverPage {
  private image: string = null;
  private text: string = null;

  constructor(private navParams: NavParams) {
    this.image = navParams.get('image');
    this.text = navParams.get('text');
  }
}
```

And it displays this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my mistake. I had "quotation" marks in the wrong place.